# Problems running JAR file in US computers

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

There are some issues running executable JAR files in different countries. In USA, I have set up a computer in German (Windows has been set up in Germany). The JAR file ran with no problems. Then I tried to change to an American computer and had an issue in running the JAR file. (The program freezes)

Can you imagine that there is a problem with Windows, Java or any relevant setup in different countries influencing how a JAR file runs?

Note: 
1. The JAR file has code to read/write files in the computer system and also has multi threading 
2. I use the command **java  -jar -Xms2000M esc.jar** to run the JAR file from the windows command prompt.
3. There is no log file generation in the system and the command prompt does not show any exceptions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not a problem with your jar file. It sounds like a problem with java installation and / or security policies.

Can you reproduce this issue on another u.s. windows system ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue in a Japanese computer. (Windows has been set up in Japanese). What do you think, which security policy might be causing a JAR file to run differently?